# Unable to get the text from a webpage using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests-html

I am simply trying to grab all of the text from the main page. This code returns nothing. The end-goal is to scan the page for when the shirt icon appears. If it does click into the match. Thanks in advance :

[First Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMUKI.png) attached is html of one match which I would like to loop through all of them on the page
[Second picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8hI8.png) attached is html of shirt icon appearing

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument(" - incognito")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH,options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.flashscore.com/")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

try:
    main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "sportName soccer"))
    )
    print(main.text)
except:
    print("No Text Found")
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all the text inside that element:

```
main = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'sportName soccer')]")
print(main.text)
```

To get only the events

```
listofevents = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'event__match event__match--oneLine event__match--scheduled')]")
for i in listofevents:
print(i.text)
```

Comment: This works really well thanks. If I then wanted to go on from each element and grab the id of each match IF and WHEN a shirt icon appears I am currently getting an error using this code` <code>listofevents = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'event__match event__match--oneLine event__match--scheduled')]")
for match in listofevents:
    n+=1
    matchid = match.id
    try:
        lineuppresent = match.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id='+matchid+']/svg[2]')
        lineuppresent.click()
    except:
        if n>5: 
            break
        
driver.quit() <code>

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your locator strategy from using class to xpath.

```
try:
    main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="live-table"]/div[@class="event"]/div[@class="leagues--live "]/div[@class="sportName soccer"]')))
    print(main.text)
except:
    print("No Text Found")
driver.quit()
```